# How can i determine which link with the same name is pressed

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

When the user clicks one of these links and we go to the next JSP page, I'll need to somehow get this record number

```
<table> <tr>
                    <td><strong><font size="5">User Name</font></strong></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><strong><font size="5">Title</font></strong></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><strong><font size="5">Description</font></strong></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><strong><font size="5">Date Published</font></strong></td></tr>



                <% for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        IdeaList az = (IdeaList) list.elementAt(i);
                        //     System.out.println(az);
                 %>

                <tr> <td><%=az.getUsername()%></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><%=az.getTitle()%></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><%=az.getDescription()%></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><%=az.getLastModification()%></td>
                    <td><a href="http://localhost:8080/BankOfIdeass/Controller?action=View&idea=<%=az.getIdeaId()%>">View Idea</a></td> 
                </tr>

                <% }%>

            </table>
```

I want to when i click on view idea ,it open jsp with details of this idea from database

Comment: Posting an example of what you have would be nice.

Comment: This isn't a clear question :(

Comment: how can i know what's link is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value in the URL and get it on the next page. Example:

```
book.jsp?id=value
```

Comment: <a href="controller?action=view&id=1">View</a>
<a href="controller?action=view&id=2">View</a>
<a href="controller?action=view&id=3">View</a>

Comment: Now,in controller/jsp use request.getParameter("id") to get the value of id attribute of the link that is clicked.